# Replacing many values in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I need to replace values in a big DataFrame before saving (in fact i read 1M+ SAS table in 200k row chunks, format data and save to `castra` storage). I use `Series.map(dict).combine_first(Series)` to replace values and it's fast. But it cannot be used to replace values with `NaN`, cause `combine_first` returns old value back in this case. I've tried to use `replace` method, it was working for some time and finally gave "cannot compare types object and str" error.

Here's a related code sample (200k int Series and 12k items replacement dict):

```
sl = pd.Series(range(200000))
r = {i: -i for i in range(100000,112000)}
sl2 = sl.map(r).combine_first(sl)
>> sl2[100001]
>> -100001.0

sl3 = sl.replace(r)
>> TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int32)' and 'int'
```

The 1st method somehow converted int to float (it's not an issue cause i mostly have string data), the 2nd one slo-o-owly ate 20% of 8gb RAM before the error.

So how can i replace values and set some values to NaN?

Comment: If your r can cover the entire range of sl, then you don't need the .combine_first(sl) and the .map(r) will produce nans wherever you define them in r

Comment: Like:  r2 = {i: np.nan if ((i > 100000)&(i < 100100)) else i for i in range(200000)}

Comment: Then:  sl2 = sl.map(r2)

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? It's not clear to me. `sl.map(r).combine_first(sl)` but faster?

Comment: I think he wants sl.map(r).combine_first(sl) that could replace some elements with nan.  sl.replace(r) could do it but it's too slow.

Comment: @crow_t_robot right! Also i don't understand, why `replace` gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to combine both methods. At first `map` not-null values then `replace` with null values

```
def replace(s, d):
    if type(d) is not pd.Series:
        d = pd.Series(d)
    dn = d[d.isnull()]
    if len(dn):
        d = d[~d.index.isin(dn.index)]
    if len(d):
        s = s.map(d).combine_first(s)
    if len(dn):
        s = s.replace(dn)
    return s
```